# What is the best way to earn gold for a level 80?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Gold is very essential in the game. Tier 3 cultural sets cost over 100g. Many other stuff also requires a large amount of gold.

What are some good methods of earning gold fast for a level 80?

Comment: This question's answers have become a bit outdated with time, especially because of the recent revamps to dungeon loot.  I don't have enough rep to set a bounty, but I'd really like to see some more recent answers to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to earn gold.

1. **Follow the zerg in Straits of Devastation.** Players have found a way to do dynamic events in a manner results in a never ending chain. Each event rewards a good amount of exp, gold and karma. Pop a karma booster for more karma. This is by far the best way of earning gold and karma. The downside is that it is a very boring method.
2. **Caudecus' Manor.** This level 40 dungeon is truly the easiest dungeon to grind. A good group of players can clear this dungeon in 15minutes. Each completion rewards 13 silver as well as plenty of level dependent loot to salvage. This is a great way to farm gold and crafting mats like gossamer scraps and orichulam ores. The downside is that it does not reward karma. It can also turn into quite a grind.
3. **Citadel of Flames.** This dungeon's reward is not as good as Caudecus' Manner. However, I noticed it tends to drop quite a nice amount of loot bags which give crafting mats like  bones and vials of blood. Selling those on the trading post can result in quite a bit of profit. One nice upside is that is is quite challenging which makes it a nice alternative to the easy yet boring Caudecus' Manor.
4. **WvWvW.** There are plenty of dynamic events in here. Capturing points all give good rewards. The biggest upside to WvWvW is that it has a huge fun factor.

**Sept 17th Edit:**

The latest [patch](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/news/Update-Notes-September-17th-2012) reduced the rewards for running dungeons constantly. This would reduce the farming effectiveness of Caudecus' Manor and Citadel of Flames in story mode. It looks like the current fastest way to earn gold/karma would be to fight in WvWvW when your server is evenly matched with the opponent.

Comment: Don't forget that probably the fastest way to earn gold is to just outright buy it with real money by purchasing gems. While it's not through traditional gameplay, it *is* still an option.

Comment: @FAE And this is *exactly* how ArenaNet would want you to do it!

Comment: FAE and BunjiquoBianco: your comments made me laugh! It's true, though, that it would be the fastest way to earn gold; whether it's the "best" I couldn't tell.

Comment: Sitting in my cubical coding all day sure makes me feel like I earnt my gems!

Comment: think about $/hour, grinding for 3 hours to get 3 gold or paying $10 for 10 gold, if you earn more than $3/hour then it's more worth it to buy the gold with $  (all numbers made up, I don't know the actual rate)

Comment: For the dungeon grinding, are you doing this in Story or Explorable mode?

Comment: I also heard that Arena Net is banning account of people abusing bugs. So just be advised.

Comment: @FAE Story mode.

Comment: @M'vy ANet actually nerfed the effects of DE to have diminishing returns the longer you do them without a break. So it is a clear sign from ANet IMO that they won't be banning for this particular "bug".

Comment: @Rodolfo The current ratio of Gems->Gold is hardly 1 dollar=1gold though. Currently it's something like 100 gems-> ~30s. Therefore if you wanted to buy 800 gems and turn it into gold you would get about $10= 2.4g.

Comment: The biggest downside to WvWvW is that if your world happens to be losing, equipment repairs can wind up costing you more than you earn.

Comment: Also remember not to salvage every item that drops: only salvage if you're likely to get something more valuable from the salvage than what the base item's worth + 1/25 of the salvage kit's cost. Salvaging fine and masterwork items is usually not worth it, and these should be sold intact; rares are usually worth salvaging with a high rare-item chance salvage kit to try for ectos.

Comment: @Merus Not quite true tbh. I have got quite a few level 400 mats like gossamer scraps from using fine salvage kits on fine and masterwork items. I have generally earned back the cost of the kit and more. I use the black lion kit for level 70+ rares for ectos.

Comment: @TerryChia The [September 17th patch](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/news/Update-Notes-September-17th-2012) reduced rewards for speed running dungeons, [Caudecus's Manor included](http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/102leo/caduceus_manor_completely_ruined/). You may want to update your answer in light of this.

Comment: @FAE Thanks, just saw the patch. Gonna edit it in now.

Comment: @TerryChia Black Lion Kit has a lower chance to reward rare items, and is specially made to salvage sigils. I would still argue that CoF is one of the easiest ways to earn money.

Comment: @Domocus Interesting, is there a reliable source on that? I don't think the description states it outright am i wrong?

Comment: The description does state it outright, as the ectoplasm is a rare material. (Black Lion Kit only has a 10% chance of this)

Comment: If you want to get Ecto's use the mystic forge to make a 'Mystic Salvage Kit' which has 250 uses and 25% of rare mats. Always use this kit on any item lv70+ for a chance at rare mats.  
[http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Salvage_Kit]

Comment: @Domocus: I agree about CoF, but the [Black Lion Salvage Kit](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Salvage_Kit) has a 50% chance of getting rare materials, not 10%. This makes it better than the [Mystic Salvage Kit](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Salvage_Kit) at 25% for getting ectos (except of course the number of uses is much higher on the latter) plus you _always_ get the rune or sigil.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest, and most efficient, ways of farming for gold, is by farming for particular items and then using the Trading Post to sell them.

**Crafting Materials:**

Farming these can grant you an extraordinary amount of money, but you will have to watch the Trading Post and test differing zones for the most efficient items.

The Trading Post is primarily based on casual players. These players, which consist of about 70% of the player base, are the primary buyers on the trading post. By watching crafting materials, you will begin to detect patterns in prices that typically demonstrate the average level of casual players.

For the time being, I would focus on crafting materials above Tier 3, which will net you a pretty penny on the Trading Post.

I would also make note of Orichalum Nodes and farm these whenever they are up.

Comment: The problem with this is, as you said, the market will continually shift, requiring a fair amount of upkeep and flexibility. I get the feeling that this doesn't really fit the 'get gold fast' mentality that this question was asked with.

Comment: While the market will continually shift, it does so very slowly, as referenced by the number of casual players. For the time being, the market is still based on T2 materials, and will move into T3 within the next week. As a level 80, there's no need to farm these lower level crafting materials, so a buffer zone (at around T4), should suffice for a steady amount of gold.

Comment: For the TP, could be handy, http://tpcalc.com/?redirect=namtar.com

Answer (score 0):

Currently the most reliable way to earn gold quickly is to do [CoF](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Citadel_of_Flame) in explorable mode, especially [Path 1](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Citadel_of_Flame_(explorable)#Ferrah) and, to a lesser extent, [Path 2](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Citadel_of_Flame_(explorable)#Magg). Path 1 can be done in under 10 minutes and Path 2 takes only a little longer (more difficult as well though).

If you're not familiar with CoF runs, I'd suggest taking a look at [Strife's excellent guides](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzYy8FVzP3HZlFcukgbj9tJuUN_40ioJW) and having a go with your friends, guildies, or just a [PUG](http://guildwars.wikia.com/wiki/PUG) - the easiest way to find one is to use http://gw2lfg.com/ and try to `/join <name>` of someone looking for group members (beware the freakish elitists out there who get upset if you're not perfectly equipped and the run takes 10 instead of 8 minutes...). The number of [charr carvings](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Flame_Legion_Charr_Carving) you're rewarded decreases if you do multiple runs of the same path on the same day with the same character, but you still get a nice 26 silver per completed run, plus several [Bags of Wondrous Goods](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bag_of_Wondrous_Goods) with more money, among other things. With a good group, you can make several gold per hour this way.

Another nice way to make gold, though one that is less reliable and requires some crafting skills as well as some "starting capital", is to "craft and play the market". The [Spidy site](http://www.gw2spidy.com/) is a great resource for this, with up-to-date prices on items and very informative crafting break-downs that show you all the needed components at a glance. Just beware that firstly, some recipes (like [this one](http://www.gw2spidy.com/recipe/6512)) don't consider dungeon trophies to "cost" anything, so if you don't have them, you can't craft it, which makes the assumption of your "profit" somewhat misleading, and secondly, that if you craft an expensive item and match the lowest seller, you may be sitting on it indefinitely if there's nobody who wants to buy it for that price. So inform yourself about an item's desirability before you commit to crafting it for a profit.